# Python 3: The maximum number of consecutive equal elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a sequence of integer numbers ending with the number 0. Determine the length of the widest fragment where all the elements are equal to each other.
i.e. 4,4,4,4,31,31,5,5,5,5,5,5 should return 6

This is a task I was given in school and have no idea how to complete. Please help...

Here is the code I have so far:

```
seq = []
distance = []
x = int(input())
while x != 0:
    seq.append(x)
    x = int(input())

n = str(seq)

for num in seq:
    distance.append(len(seq[''.join(n).find(str(num))-1:''.join(n).rfind(str(num))+1]))

print(max(distance))
```

Comment: See [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), second example: `max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(seq)), key=len)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441521/find-maximum-length-of-consecutive-repeated-numbers-in-a-list-python) you may use `itertools.groupby` to achieve this:

```
import itertools
a = [4,4,4,4,31,31,5,5,5,5,5,5]
z = [(x[0], len(list(x[1]))) for x in itertools.groupby(a)]
print max(z, key=lambda x:x[1])[1] #6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 element = [1,7,7,7,7,9,9,1,0]
 i = 1
 counter = 1
 max_frag =0
 while element[i] != 0:
     i+=1
     if element[i]== element[i-1]:
        counter+=1
    else:
        max_frag = max(max_frag,counter)
        counter = 1
print max_frag
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code for reference. Code-only answers tend to be of low utility and can be confusing.