# How to find the maximum consecutive occurrences of a number in python

Tags: python

I want to find out the maximum number of consecutive occurrences of a number in python.
I am using the following code from stack overflow.

```
from itertools import groupby
b= [1,2,45,55,5,4,3,2,5,5,6,5456,5456,5456,7,67,6,6]

print(b)

def occurrence():
    occurrence, num_times = 0, 0
    for key, values in groupby(b, lambda x : x):
        val = len(list(values))
        if val >= occurrence:
            occurrence, num_times =  key, val
    return occurrence, num_times

occurrence, num_times = occurrence()
print("%d occurred %d times" % (occurrence, num_times))
```

I get the following answer:

```
5 occurred 2 times
```

The answer should be 5456 because it occurred 3 times.
Can any body help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: what if you have more than one item with max occurrences?

Comment: Related: [Find maximum length of consecutive repeated numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36441521/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only change you need is

```
if val >= num_times:
```

your code is comparing the length of the current group with the last `key`.

this returns the **last** item with maximal consecutive occurrence (if there were three times `5` later in the list this would be selected).

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that code by using the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function to find the maximum `num_times`.

```
from itertools import groupby

b = [1, 2, 45, 55, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 5456, 5456, 5456, 7, 67, 6, 6]

num_times, occurrence = max((len(list(values)), key) for key, values in groupby(b))
print("%d occurred %d times" % (occurrence, num_times))
```

**output**

```
5456 occurred 3 times
```

There's no need to give `groupby` that inefficient `lambda x: x`: if you don't give it a key function it uses the identity function by default.

---

FWIW, there's a more efficient way to calculate the length of a `groupby` group. It doesn't matter here, but it's handy when the groups are large. Rather than converting the group to a list & getting its length, we can loop over the group and use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to count the items in the group. Just change

```
len(list(values))
```

to

```
sum(1 for _ in values)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following generator expression:

```
print('{1} occurred {0} times'.format(*max((len(list(g)), k) for k, g in groupby(b))))
```

This outputs:

```
5456 occurred 3 times
```

Comment: Can you also explain this large one liner. It helps, otherwise it's just a solution without explanation and has limited transferability to other similar problems